# Insert statement with join

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have two tables `[Departments]` with ID, Department_Name, [Employees] Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Dep_ID foreign key to Departments.ID

First I `select *` Departments Name and display it in a dropdownlist from the `Departments` table:

[image]

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Dep_Name" 
     DataValueField="Dep_Name">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Attend_DBConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [Dep_Name] FROM [Departments]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to select the Department Name from the dropdownlist and insert into `Employees` table `Dep_Id` column which matches with that `Department_name` selected from `Department` table

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial from Microsoft on how to read related data in ASP.Net core.
Same example is available for entity framework as well. google Contoso University.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio[enter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio%5Benter) link description here][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)